# Create multiple different CSS/Javascript pop-up

Tags: javascript, css, dynamic, popup

I'm looking for a way to create CSS/Javascript based pop-up windows. I'm fetching information from my database depending on how many (example) cars there is. I want to be able to create  an equal number of CSS/Javascript based pop-up windows to each car I have in the database to show more information about the car in the pop-up.

The trick is - of course - that I want the right information about a certain car to show up when you click on the related link.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you only ever want a popup to be open for one car at any given time, you can have a single popup element that you show/hide and reposition when they click on a link, then load the content for the specific car using AJAX.

If you want them to be able to open popups for multiple cars at any given time, dynamically generate a new popup element when they click on a link, position it correctly and then load the content for the specific car using AJAX.

I'd suggest using a Javascript framework (such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)) because it will make the process considerably easier. There are also a number of plugins that you could look into using that perform this functionality.

Comment: Found exactly what I wanted with this superb script: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples Thanks for answer still!